# I want my Code to Return Random Names

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I want my code to return random names in the textboxes but it always gives me an error. here is my code :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


 TextBox1.Text = Evaluate(Choose(RandBetween(1, 3), "Kwezi", "MAy", "FR"))
 TextBox2.Text = Evaluate(Choose(RandBetween(1, 3), "Kwezi", "MAy", "FR"))
 TextBox3.Text = Evaluate(Choose(RandBetween(1, 3), "Kwezi", "MAy", "FR"))


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    TextBox1.Text = Choose(WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 3), "Kwezi", "MAy", "FR")
    TextBox2.Text = Choose(WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 3), "Kwezi", "MAy", "FR")
    TextBox3.Text = Choose(WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 3), "Kwezi", "MAy", "FR")
End Sub
```